# Dynamic Text Over Seekbar Thumb Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, seekbar, android-seekbar

I created a series of sliders for selecting values, when the activity starts all the thumbs and their corresponding dynamic text appear at the same starting point.  Once you move the slider to the right the dynamic text never really stay centred to the Thumb.  When the slider is all the way to the right the dynamic text falls off the screen in some cases.

[image: Seekbar Left Edge]  [image: Seekbar Middle]  [image: Seekbar Right Edge]

What I want to accomplish is all the dynamic text to appear on the left side like the Score Slider on the left (see first image), when sliding the the thumb anywhere between the min and the max value the dynamic text should be centred to the Thumb (see second image).  When the slider is at the maximum range all the dynamic text should look like the Spares and Splits sliders (see third image).

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ca.rvogl.scoreui.MainActivity">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarScore"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:max="300"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarScore"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarStrikes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:max="12"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStrikes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarStrikes"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarSpares"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSpares"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarSpares"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarSplits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSplits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarSplits"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarSplitConversions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewSplitConversions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarSplitConversions"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarOpenFrames"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:max="11"
        android:progress="0"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="false" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewOpenFrames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarOpenFrames"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SeekBar seekBarGutterballs;
    private TextView textViewScore;
    private TextView textViewStrikes;
    private TextView textViewSpares;
    private TextView textViewSplits;
    private TextView textViewSplitConversions;
    private TextView textViewOpenFrames;
    private TextView textViewGutterballs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SeekBar seekBarScore = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekBarScore );
        textViewScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
        SeekBar seekBarStrikes = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekBarStrikes );
        textViewStrikes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStrikes);
        SeekBar seekBarSpares = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekBarSpares );
        textViewSpares = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSpares);
        SeekBar seekBarSplits = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekBarSplits );
        textViewSplits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSplits);
        SeekBar seekBarSplitConversions = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekBarSplitConversions );
        textViewSplitConversions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSplitConversions);
        SeekBar seekBarOpenFrames = (SeekBar) findViewById( R.id.seekBarOpenFrames );
        textViewOpenFrames = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewOpenFrames);
        // Score Seek Bar
        textViewScore.setText("Score: " + seekBarScore.getProgress());
        seekBarScore.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                                  int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewScore.setText("Score" + progress);
                        //textViewScore.setY(280);
                        textViewScore.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2);
                        progress = progresValue;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // Display the value in textview
                        textViewScore.setText("Score: "+progress);
                    }
                });
        // Strikes Seek Bar
        textViewStrikes.setText("Strikes: " + seekBarStrikes.getProgress());
        seekBarStrikes.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                                  int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewStrikes.setText("Strikes: " + progress);
                        //textViewStrikes.setY(280);
                        textViewStrikes.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2);
                        progress = progresValue;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // Display the value in textview
                        textViewStrikes.setText("Strikes " + progress);
                    }

                });
        // Spares Seek Bar
        textViewSpares.setText("Spares: " + seekBarSpares.getProgress());
        seekBarSpares.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                                  int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 4 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewSpares.setText("Spares: " + progress);
                        //textViewSpares.setY(460);
                        textViewSpares.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 4);
                        progress = progresValue;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // Display the value in textview
                        textViewSpares.setText("Spare: "+progress );
                    }

                });
        // Splits Seek Bar
        textViewSplits.setText("Splits: " + seekBarSplits.getProgress());
        seekBarSplits.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                                  int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 4 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewSplits.setText("Splits: " + progress);
                        //textViewSplits.setY(100);
                        textViewSplits.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 4);
                        progress = progresValue;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // Display the value in textview
                        textViewSplits.setText("Splits: "+progress );
                    }

                });
        // Split Conversions Seek Bar
        textViewSplitConversions.setText("Split Conversions: " + seekBarSplitConversions.getProgress());
        seekBarSplitConversions.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                                  int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 4 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewSplitConversions.setText("Split Conversions: " + progress);
                        //textViewSplits.setY(100);
                        textViewSplitConversions.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 4);
                        progress = progresValue;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // Display the value in textview
                        textViewSplitConversions.setText("Split Conversions: "+progress );
                    }

                });
        // Open Frames Seek Bar
        textViewOpenFrames.setText("Open Frames: " + seekBarOpenFrames.getProgress());
        seekBarOpenFrames.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
                new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    int progress = 0;
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                                  int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progress * (seekBar.getWidth() - 4 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewOpenFrames.setText("Open Frames: " + progress);
                        //textViewSplits.setY(100);
                        textViewOpenFrames.setX(seekBar.getX() + val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 4);
                        progress = progresValue;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // Display the value in textview
                        textViewOpenFrames.setText("Open Frames: "+progress );
                    }

                });
    }
}
```

I have gone through several different posts, but cannot seem to find anything that might help me out.   If anyone can provide some insight on this I would greatly appreciate it.

I have also tried the following code:

```
textViewScore.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
                        double pourcent = progress / (double) seekBarScore.getMax();
                        int offset = seekBar.getThumbOffset();
                        int seekWidth = seekBarScore.getWidth();
                        int val = (int) Math.round(pourcent * (seekWidth - 2 * offset));
                        int labelWidth = textViewScore.getWidth();
                        textViewScore.setX(offset + seekBarScore.getX() + val
                                - Math.round(pourcent * offset)
                                - Math.round(pourcent * labelWidth/2));
```

I got this from here: [Add dynamic text over Android SeekBar thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722746/add-dynamic-text-over-android-seekbar-thumb)

Images from using Answer Below:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Point maxSizePoint = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(maxSizePoint);
int maxX = maxSizePoint.x;
textViewScore.setX(textViewScore.getMeasuredWidth() + (val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2) > maxX ? (maxX - textViewScore.getMeasuredWidth() - 16) : val + seekBar.getThumbOffset() / 2);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I've tried with a single `seekbar` following is the **`code`** and **`output`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int maxX;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SeekBar seekBarScore = findViewById(R.id.seekBarScore);
        final TextView textViewScore = findViewById(R.id.textViewScore);
        textViewScore.setText("Split Conversions : " + seekBarScore.getProgress());
        Point maxSizePoint = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(maxSizePoint);
        maxX = maxSizePoint.x;
        seekBarScore.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                        int val = (progressValue * (seekBar.getWidth() - 2 * seekBar.getThumbOffset())) / seekBar.getMax();
                        textViewScore.setText("Split Conversions : " + progressValue);
                        int textViewX = val - (textViewScore.getWidth() / 2);
                        int finalX = textViewScore.getWidth() + textViewX > maxX ? (maxX - textViewScore.getWidth() - 16) : textViewX + 16/*your margin*/;
                        textViewScore.setX(finalX < 0 ? 16/*your margin*/ : finalX);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: With the code you provided above I am getting pretty much the same results.

Comment: I also tried messing around with the values in the code but the results were also similar to the screen shots above.

Comment: @RobertVogl with the solution i provided i am able to not letting the text go beyond the screen. Haven't done anything for keeping them in the center

Comment: I was using the first code that you provided in the wrong location.  It appears to be fine now.  Thanks for you assistance