# How to move Textview automatically below android Seekbar thumb?

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have custom **Seekbar** which shows the status of shipping and below it **TextView** which shows the package's(goods) location.All i want is to move the text automatically along with thumb without touching the **Seekbar**,i have tried different solutions but no one worked,i don't know if it's possible to do this or not,if anyone can help i will be very thankful to him.

> My output

[image]

> MyCode:

```
private void setProgress(int statusNum) {
            switch (statusNum) {
                case 1:
                    seekBar.setProgress(1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    seekBar.setProgress(2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    seekBar.setProgress(3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    seekBar.setProgress(4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    seekBar.setProgress(5);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    seekBar.setProgress(6);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    seekBar.setProgress(7);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    seekBar.setProgress(8);
                    break;

            }
            int seekBarWidth = seekBar.getWidth() - seekBar.getPaddingLeft() - seekBar.getPaddingRight();
            float displacement = seekBarWidth * (seekBar.getProgress() / seekBar.getMax());
            txtStatus.setX(displacement);
        }
```

**EDIT:**
Added xml

```
    <com.warkiz.tickseekbar.TickSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tsb_ticks_count="8"
            app:tsb_thumb_color="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tsb_thumb_size="12dp"
            app:tsb_show_tick_marks_type="oval"
            app:tsb_tick_marks_color="#33000000"
            app:tsb_tick_marks_size="6dp"
            app:tsb_track_background_color="#1A00C853"
            app:tsb_track_background_size="2dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:tsb_progress="1.0"
            app:tsb_min="1"
            app:tsb_max="8"
            app:tsb_track_progress_color="@color/colorGreen"
            app:tsb_track_progress_size="4dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:text="Прийнято"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/seekbar"
            />
```

Comment: can you show the XML file ?

Comment: @noureldienmohamed i already added you can see

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722746/add-dynamic-text-over-android-seekbar-thumb ?

Comment: @noureldienmohamed i tried but this custom seekbar that i use doesn't have `thumbOffset` value

Comment: there is solution but it is not the best , add textView for each number (8) then in switch you can appear  and disappear what you want .

Comment: @noureldienmohamed thanks for help i also think about this if i can't find solution,i will use this idea:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211941/discussion-between-mohammed-qadah-and-noureldien-mohamed).

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here:

```
        txtStatus.setX(displacement);
```

**Don't** change the position of view with this method. Instead use standard layout params and edit the margins (in this case `marginLeft`) and adjust it to achieve your goal.

```java
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) txtStatus.getLayoutParams();
p.marginLeft = someValue;
txtStatus.requestLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but  i didn't get it.Can you please explain how it should be with seekbar?can you write the whole method?

Comment: use the code i gave you instead of the line setX, adjust the displacement , use displacement as someValue in my code

Comment: i used it but it didn't help the text doesn't move along with thumb(