# How add text Seekbar thumb?

Tags: android, seekbar, custom-view, android-seekbar

I'm trying to create custom SeekBar.I want to add textview or text on seekbar's thumb and change this textview dynamically. How can i do this ?

My design is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ifi.png

Comment: have a look at this nice tut: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: Post you design file screen shot here,

Comment: like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/k1ifi.png

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272384/how-add-textview-in-middle-of-seekbar-thumb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this function for a solution;

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(Bitmap thumb, String text) {

Bitmap bm = thumb.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#288ca0"));
paint.setTextSize(bm.getHeight() / 3);
paint.setTypeface(type);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
canvas.drawText(text , bm.getWidth() / 4 - bm.getWidth()/10,
        bm.getHeight() / 2 + bm.getHeight() / 10, paint);

return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

Comment: where do you call this function from?