# How to create Step wise - Progress Bar in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I want to enroll user's voice as input for 3 times. For that I want to create a UI (the **XML** File) which would animate by moving from step 1 to step 2 when first recording is done which would be controlled by start stop buttons. and eventually move to step 3.....
Something like this -

[image]

I dont know how to explain to google this! Please help!!

Answer (score 11):

The most similar Android component to the image you provided is probably Android's discrete `SeekBar`:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="3" />
```

`style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"` together with `android:max="3"` will divide the bar in 3 parts and delimit them with 4 ticks which can represent in your case user input phases.

The attribute `progress` will then reflect the phases with the integer values 0, 1, 2, 3 which you can set to go on with the progress:

```
private SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

public void nextPhase() {
    mSeekBar.setProgress(mSeekBar.getProgress() + 1);
}
```

Note that `SeekBar` is intended for user input so if it has to be controlled only by your button/vocal input events the normal behavior has to be disabled:

```
mSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // True doesn't propagate the event
        // the user cannot move the indicator
        return true;
    }
});
```

If you want to display some text next to every step tick but don't want to extend `SeekBar` you can try to align 4 `TextView`s below the bar with a `LinearLayout` or `TableLayout` and tweak `layout_weight` and widths, here the even view distribution topic is discussed [is it possible to evenly distribute buttons across the width of an android linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470420/is-it-possible-to-evenly-distribute-buttons-across-the-width-of-an-android-linea).

However the animation won't work smoothly in the discrete version of `SeekBar` because of the small values of `progress`. If you want an animation you should use a normal 0-100 progress `SeekBar` or create your custom one to support steps, something like this:

```
public class StepsSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    int mSteps;
    int mCurrentStep;
    int mStepWidth;

    public StepsSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int steps) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mSteps = steps;
        mCurrentStep = 0;
        mStepWidth = 100 / mSteps;
    }

    public nextStep() {
        // Animate progress to next step
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "progress", mStepWidth * mCurrentStep, mStepWidth * (++mCurrentStep));
        animator.setDuration(/* Duration */);
        animator.start();
    }
}
```

The aspect of the bar can be customized in the theme:

```
<style name="StepsSeekBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly"></item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable"></item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable"></item>
    <item name="android:thumb"><!-- The circle drawable --></item>
    <item name="android:focusable"></item>
</style>
<!-- In the discrete SeekBar -->
<item name="tickMark"><!-- The circles indicating steps --></item>
```

Here [How add TextView in middle of SeekBar thumb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272384/how-add-textview-in-middle-of-seekbar-thumb) you can find more information on how to add text in the progress thumb.

The normal horizontal `ProgressBar` can also be used but it doesn't show an indicator, it has to be drawn in a custom implementation.