# Horizontal Step Progress Bar

Tags: android, kotlin

How could I implement the design showed in this screenshot with an indicator that shows which activity am on out of the wo options with some text under each step in the progress bar in Kotlin?

[Link for the screenshot..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XTAR.png)

I tried styling the progress bar but didn't have any luck doing so.

Comment: I hope this response is helpful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989575/how-to-create-step-wise-progress-bar-in-android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create Step wise - Progress Bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44989575/how-to-create-step-wise-progress-bar-in-android)